# Angular Material Drag & Drop - Get parent object that contains the cdkDropListData

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm using Angular & Material 14 and have drag & drop in my application. Everything works, but when I transfer a `child` item to a child-list of another `parent` object, I need a way to know which `parent` object it was.

This is the object structure:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Parent Container 1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Child 1",
                "parentName":  "Parent Container 1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Child 2",
                "parentName":  "Parent Container 1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Child 3",
                "parentName":  "Parent Container 1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Parent Container 2",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Child 1",
                "parentName":  "Parent Container 2"
            },
            {
                "name": "Child 2",
                "parentName":  "Parent Container 2"
            },
            {
                "name": "Child 3",
                "parentName":  "Parent Container 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the template:

```html
<!-- Parent Container -->
<div class="parent-container"
    [id]="articleDropListId + i"
    cdkDropList
    [cdkDropListData]="parent.children"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">

    <!-- Children -->
    <div class="children" *ngFor="let child of parent.children" cdkDrag>

        <!-- Child -->
        <div class="child">
            {{child.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the function I use.

```js
public drop(event: CdkDragDrop<ChildModel[]>): void {
    if (event.previousContainer !== event.container) {
        // if transfered between two parent containers, I need the name of the new parent container
        transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data, event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        const movedChild: ChildModel = event.container.data[event.previousIndex];
        this.apiService.moveChild(movedChild, >>parentName<<);
    } else if(event.previousContainer === event.container) {
        moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        const movedChild: ChildModel = event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex];
        this.apiService.moveChild(movedChild, >>parentName<<);
    }
}
```

So I first move the child with the provided methods from @angular/cdk/drag-drop and afterwards I have to make a request to the server and send the moved `child` object as well as the new `parentName` of the current `parent`.

Is there anyway to retrieve the current `parent` object from the drop event?

Comment: Can u create a demo code on stackblitz.com

Comment: in `[cdkDropListData]` you can use "whatever", so, e.g. you can use `[cdkDropListData]="parent"` and to transfer elements of the array use `event.previousContainer.data.children` and `event.Container.data.children`. NOTE: the function transferArrayItems and moveItemInArray are only functions to change two arrays, you can see the functions in [github](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-utils.ts)

Comment: @Eliseo I haven't thought about that, but I'll try it. Thank you